# Use treesitter to jump to next argument without going into nested function calls

Tags: neovim, macro, plugin-treesitter

I'm hoping to write a macro that involves jumping to a second argument of a function call and deleting it. The function arguments will sometimes include nested function calls, sometimes not, will sometimes be on multiple lines, and sometimes all on one line.

I was hoping to use [nvim-treesitter-textobjects](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects/) to jump to the next argument via something like this:

```lua
require'nvim-treesitter.configs'.setup {
  textobjects = {
     move = {
       enable = true,
       set_jumps = true,

       goto_previous_start = {
         ["[["] = "@parameter.inner",
       },
       goto_next_start = {
         ["]]"] = "@parameter.inner",
       },
     },
  },
}
```

And then for example, with a code snippet like this:

```go
func foo(a, b int) int {
  return a * b
}

func bar(a, b int) int {
  return a + b
}

func main() {
  foo(
    bar(
      1, 
      2,
    ),
    3,
  )
}
```

When my cursor is on `bar`, and I hit `]]`, I'd like it to jump to `3`, the next argument at the same level as the current node. However, it unfortunately jumps to `1`, the next argument at the lower level of the nested function call.

Any suggestions for how to achieve this desired jump?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I did not find a suitable solution using custom queries or with treesitter-textobjects, however I found an [issue](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects/issues/183) in the repo which described a similar problem.

To achieve the behavior you want, I hacked up this function using `ts_utils`. So all we need now is just to bind it to a key.

```lua
vim.keymap.set("n", "]]", function()
  local t = require("nvim-treesitter.ts_utils")
  t.goto_node(t.get_next_node(t.get_node_at_cursor(), true, true), false, true)
end)

vim.keymap.set("n", "[[", function()
  local t = require("nvim-treesitter.ts_utils")
  t.goto_node(t.get_previous_node(t.get_node_at_cursor(), true, true), false, true)
end)
```

These mappings would actually work on nodes of any type, not just argument lists.

Here is each of the positions the cursor (`|`) visits when pressing `]]` and/or `[[`:

```go
foo(
  |bar|(
    1, 
    2,
  ),
  |3,
)
```

Example motion in lua table:

```lua
o = {
  |a = |1,
  |2,
  |c = |{ 31, 32 },
  |4,
}
```

**Note**

- Last argument `true` to `goto_node` avoids adding the jump to jumplist
- Arguments `true, true` to `get_next_node` allows jumping to next parent

Please see the docs for `ts_utils` for reference:

https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/blob/master/doc/nvim-treesitter.txt